# How to reduce the padding/spacement from dynamic generated div tags in html+css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have 4 selects in which I can choose: Area, specialty, group, and subgroup of healthy related procedures. Every time I select a subgroup it will render the procedures inside the page. My problem is that the div's height is divided in equal parts to every row, which causes the padding to be a lot bigger than I want. I need to select other options so that the padding will be reduced to the minimum.
Below are some pictures to clarify the problem.

[image: Undesired behavior]
Undesired behavior

[image]
This is what happens when I change the procedimento_row div height to 30px or to *fit-content*. The height is reduced but is creates a padding to fill all the div

[image]
Expected height and padding ever since the first time a subgroup is selected

Right below is the function that generates the rows

```
$("body").on("change", "#subgrupo_procedimento", function() {
    var procedimento = "";

    $.get("/procedimento/procedimentos-por-subgrupo/" + $("#subgrupo_procedimento").val(), function(data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                     
        
            procedimento += '<div class="row procedimento_row">';
            procedimento +=     '<span class="col-md-1 procedimento_options">';
            procedimento +=         '<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="procedimentos" value="'+data[i].id+'">';
            procedimento +=     '</span>';  
            procedimento +=     '<span class="col-md-3 procedimento_options">';
            procedimento +=         data[i].codigoTuss;
            procedimento +=     '</span>';
            procedimento +=     '<span class="col-md-6 procedimento_options" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'+data[i].descricao+'">';
            procedimento +=         data[i].descricao;
            procedimento +=     '</span>';      
            procedimento +=     '<span class="col-md-2 procedimento_options">';
            procedimento +=     data[i].valorPreferencial.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
            procedimento +=     '</span>';
            procedimento += '</div>';
            
        }
        $("#procedimento_table").append(procedimento);
    });
});
```

The divs "procedimento_row" are inside a div called "procedimento_table":
Here is procedimento_table css:

```
#procedimento_table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left:  0 !important;
}
```

Comment: add your code not screenshot.

Comment: I added it too. I've put descriptions in each picture, but they didn't appear. I'm editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving them a max-height of 25px in your css? It looks like they're being stretched with flex.

```
.procedimento_row {
   max-height: 25px !important; 
}
```

Edit: See this codepen for example table css
https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/OJMgqRZ

```
#procedimento_table{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}

#procedimento_row{
  min-height: 25px; 
}
```

Comment: I did. It reduces the height but keeps a margin from each row to another.
One doubt, can you see the pictures descriptions? I added it, but i can't see any of the descriptions.

Comment: It sounds like the class "procidemento_table" might be justifying content with "space-evenly" rather than "flex-start". It's difficult to say without being able to look through the actual code myself.

Comment: I think it's a css issue; I created a code pen that populates a table with the exact same sized rows. On overflow, the container doesn't grow and instead shows a scroll bar.

https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/OJMgqRZ

Comment: That's a nice way to do it. I found out that putting display: block solved the issue. But then the horizontal aligning was messed up, making it necessary to manually set margins. So I decided to work with table, thead and tbody. It solved the problem of the height and padding and I don't need to worry about horizontal aligning. However, I got a new trouble which is the <thead> width, which is not being set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `class="row"` from `<div class="row" id="procedimento_table">`. I don't see any evidence for it to be here. We have this class in it's children, this will be enough.

or add to your `#procedimento_table` next code, as long as `row` makes it `display: flex`

```
#procedimento_table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left:  0 !important;
    /* add this */
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```